# transmission-remote: How to monitor list of torrents in terminal?

Tags: command-line, transmission, monitoring, torrent-client

I have just installed transmission on my server which runs Ubuntu desktop. I have no issue with downloading files and so forth, but would like to keep a terminal window open on my work computer where I can see how far download have come.

Currently I do this with `transmission-remote -n 'user:pwd' -l`, but this just outputs the current status for the torrents at that given second. I would like a similar list, but one that keeps updating so I don't have to type the above command all the time.

Anyone know a way to do this? I saw a guy do it with this cmd: `transmission-remote-cli`.. but i don't have that.. I have `transmission-cli` but I can't get it to work as the guy with used `transmission-remote-cli` did.

Hope somebody can help :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no option to constantly monitor the status of `transmission-daemon` using `transmission-cli`, it's just not a tool made for that.

`transmission-remote-cli` on the other hand works very well for that. Do you have a specific reason to not install it?

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-remote-cli
```

You would be able to connect to the daemon simply by running:

```
transmission-remote-cli -c host:port
```

Or in case you enabled authentication on the daemon:

```
transmission-remote-cli -c username:password@host:port
```

Otherwise, yet another option would be connecting to the daemon using the web interface by visiting:

```
http://host:port/
```

Obviously `host` and `port` in the above commands / URL are to be replaced with the host and the port of the server running the daemon.

Comment: I have no idea why i haven't installed the transmission-remote-cli, maybe i though transmission-cli would be enough :)
I got everything to work after installing transmission-remote-cli and then making the following command: `transmission-remote-cli -c user:pwd@localhost`

Comment: @ThorA.Pedersen Yeah I forgot the `-c` part, thanks. Glad that you solved :)

Answer (score 13):

The `watch` command can be used to run a program periodically and show the output.

I don't have transmission installed so I can't test this, but something like

```
watch --interval 5 'transmission-remote -n 'user:pwd' -l'
```

should do what you want.

More information on `watch` by typing `man watch` or [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html)

Comment: Went with the answer above, but I did not know "watch".. definitely gonna be using that in the future :-)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To list all torrents known to `transmission-daemon` at `<host>` on `<port>` You can use

```
 transmission-remote <host:port> -t
```

Where port needs to be  specified only if `transmission-daemon` is running on a custom port.

This will list all torrents with status, for example :

```
 transmission-remote 192.168.56.121 -l   
     ID   Done       Have  ETA           Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name
      1   100%    2.73 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.0  Stopped      erst.minvh.bol.02.inversebol
      2   100%    2.78 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.1  Stopped      erst.minvh.bol.01.inversebol
      3   100%    2.41 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.6  Stopped      erst.minvh.bol.04.inversebol
      5   100%    2.82 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.5  Stopped      erst.minvh.bol.06.inversebol
```